# How to get @media to take precedence over normal styling

Tags: ios, css, iphone, media

I have two bits of CSS, one for iPhones (@media) and one for standard browsers, I basically want one OR the other to be true:

```
#currentroom_users {
    width: 175px;
    float: left;
    border-left: 1px dotted <?php echo $themeSettings['tab_border_light'];?>;
    padding-left: 5px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) { 
    #currentroom_users {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Currently, the standard #currentroom_users style always exists. If I am on an iPhone (@media) it just adds the "display: none;" but keeps all the other styling...

This is basically a DIV i want to be shown if on a desktop browser, and hidden if I am on an iPhone.

This is how it appears before I added the media tags, div shown (its the div with the usernames):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIOIb.png

This is how it appears after I added the media tags, div is not shown but the space for where it should be is still there:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xf93.png

I note that when I view the source the div still appears in the code.. not sure if this is expected.

Thanks

Comment: If the div is hidden on an iPhone, does it matter if the other styles are still being applied as long as it is set to display: none;?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styles from `#currentroom_users` is cascading down your style sheet and being applied to your styles in your media query also.  Hence CSS standing for Cascading Style Sheets...

### Cascading

To put some emphasis on this...  Your style doesn't have to be in a media query for this to happen either.  Or in other words, styles always cascade.  That's why you can run into issues where certain code will work only if it is placed above or below different code.  For example:

You have a selector with some styles like this starting on line 001...

```
001    .selector ul li {
002       color: #fff;
003       font-size: 2em;
004       text-transform: uppercase;
005    }
```

Then...  Some other styles for different selectors happen...

```
006   .differentSelector { border: 1px solid red; }
.........
.........
125   .evenMoreDifferent { background: #000; }
```

Then... You have the same selector as what was on 001 again, but adding different styles, and changing one property.

```
126   .selector ul li {
127      color: #c00;
128      background: blue;
129      border-radius: 10px;
130   }
```

### What your Browser reads...

In your browser when you load the page, the browser will read the selector with the following information:

```
.selector ul li {
   color: #c00;
   font-size: 2em;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   background: blue;
   border-radius: 10px;
}
```

### Some Definitions in regards to other questions later in your post

"I note that when I view the source the div still appears in the code.. not sure if this is expected."

CSS is a code that visually alters HTML elements.  It does NOT in any way alter the HTML itself.  When you set something to `display: none;` you are simply telling the browser that this element should not be displayed, hence it is rendered invisible.  The code is still there, and that element retains all of it's previous CSS styles in case you make it visible at any point, but it is hidden from view.

It is important to note that this makes the element "invisible" by completely removing it from the document.

[See this Wiki on the CSS Property "Display"](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display)

### Your specific case

You'll find that setting it to display: none; has infact NOT "left the space it previously occupied".  That space is "empty" now.  It appears that your columns have remained, but that is likely because your left column has a set width of some sort.

[Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating the above.](http://jsfiddle.net/eR9cU/)  There are three div's each with different colors and all 80px by 80px.  You'll see that at the bottom of the CSS sheet, I have set the .blue class to `display: none;` You'll also notice, that the yellow box is touching the red box.  If you comment out this line, you'll see the blue box reappear between the red and yellow box.

Now... [Here is a JSFiddle that uses opacity](http://jsfiddle.net/eR9cU/1/) instead of display to make the box invisible.  You'll notice that the blue box is gone, but there is a white space where it was.  That is because it has literally in ever sense of the term, been made invisible.  A key difference between actually being removed from the document.

Finally, [here is a JSFiddle using the visibility property](http://jsfiddle.net/eR9cU/2/)... Again, you'll notice the blue box is invisible, but a space for it remains.

### In summary...

- Styles always cascade, no matter what.
- Your element that is set to
  display: none; has in fact been removed from the document, it just
  doesn't visually look like it.  You likely need to adjust the width
  of the left column.
- Just because the div has been removed from the
  document, does not mean it has been removed from code.